# React router dom is not rendering a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my code

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header></Header>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/movie/:imdbID' element={<MovieDetails />} />
          <Route element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What I want is for `PageNotFound` to be shown when I enter an invalid url. But it never shows up. I tried putting it at the top, after the `<Routes>` but same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `*` to the path and it will render.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header></Header>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/movie/:imdbID' element={<MovieDetails />} />
          <Route exact path='*' element={<PageNotFound />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What does the * actually mean?

Comment: Means anything else

Answer (score 0):

Route order doesn't matter in `react-router-dom@6` as routes use a route path [ranking system](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/concepts#ranking-routes) now to match the most appropriate path. Routes are now ***always*** exactly matched as well, so there's no longer any `exact` prop.

`Route` components that match paths still need a `path` prop. Specify a wildcard `"*"` path to match anything any of the more specific paths don't.

```
<Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />} />
```

See [How dow I add a No Match (404) route in react-router v6](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/faq#how-do-i-add-a-no-match-404-route-in-react-router-v6)

Answer (score 0):

```
// use it in this way it will work 

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header></Header>

        <Routes>
          <Route   path='*' element={<PageNotFound />} />
          <Route path='/' exact element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/movie/:imdbID' element={<MovieDetails />} />
         
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```